# SOAP <faultstring>

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I am having an issue with the SOAP , when I call my services I get this error:

```
<faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring>
```

The following response is returned which doesn't give a clue where and why the error happens. How can I customize and show a proper detailed message to user so he/she know what they did wrong

I have gone through the CXF customization with `outFaultInterceptors` and `inFaultInterceptors` but I am not clear how I am gonna customize cxf.

Answer (score 4):

This means that the web service framework is returning an unchecked exception. Try running the web service on a debugger to see where the exception is happening or wrapping the web service body inside an try/catch to print the stack trace.

Comment: @JohnSaunders not CXF itself, it is supported by Java. I assume you have control over the web service implementation, so that you can debug the service while you make a request. Otherwise, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Oh, didn't know this was a Java question.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I'm not sure about it. But as the author said he was dealing with CXF, I presumed that it was Apache CXF, wich runs on Java.